# Google One-tap sign in to auto select the last user

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

With [Google One-Tap sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/retrieve-credentials) it explains you need to add `googleyolo.retrieve()` on the pages that require sign in for pages that need the user signed in and `googleyolo.hint()` for when you want to pop-up a sign-up dialogue to first-time users.

**Question:** Is it possible to auto-select the user **even though he has multiple credentials** wherever the `googleyolo.retrieve()` is executed?

My app saves the last user id in the cache, so the next time he opens the app, I want the app to auto choose his last used account.

*From the documentation:*

> *If the user has only one credential saved, the credential can be retrieved without user interaction, which makes completely automatic sign-in possible.
>
>   **When multiple credentials are saved, the user can choose** the one to use with a single tap.*

I'd like to change this behaviour (the bold text) to auto choose the last user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the product manager at Google for this library. This is something we've thought about but unfortunately currently don't have plans to support. The current experience is optimized for switching between accounts, which we've found equally common as using a previously selected account. So for now, this behavior can't be changed. I'll update this answer if there is a future revision.

Comment: Dear @Steven Soneff
This is really sad news! This means that One-Tap library cannot become my only authentication method, and I'd have to use cache or a db to retrieve the last logged in user and only use One-Tap for new users.

Comment: I'm not sure about your design decision to make it like so. When a user opens an app or web-app, he'd expect to still be logged in. What use is an authentication library if the user has to tap his own account again every time he opens the app... >_> I'm just not seeing it. : D

Comment: @mesqueeb, that's when you use the gapi login as the first line of defense for your site instead of just use yolo. If there's an existing credential that can login the user, then use that by using gapi. If not, use yolo.